# Ant Substring using regex

Tags: ant

I have a string like below
C:\deployment\dep_Scripts\OSB\configuration\sbconfig1.jar
From this string I want to extract only the file name sbconfig1

How can I do that using regex

Answer (score 0):

Ant's basename task does this : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html

```
<basename property="jar.name.without.extention" file="C:\deployment\dep_Scripts\OSB\configuration\sbconfig1.jar" suffix="jar"/>

<echo message="${jar.name.without.extention}"/>
```